# ionic-tab on menu can click but cannot see it

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

i'm newbie ionic developer. I'm use ionic-tab and i'm try to add color to the tab then 3 menu on the tab is hidden but i can click it. it hand for me to create title of this issue. let's see my issue.

**Out put**

[image]

**CSS when using inspect on google chrome**

[image: CSS when using inspect on google chrome]

when i'm check on my scss and remove it. i'm get the same result. 
How to solve this problem. Please help and thank you for visit.

Comment: your question is not very clear, are these 3 tabs supposed to be at the bottom circled in yellow? Can you add the css/code that created the issue to the question? I assume you use last version of ionic? If so, just for info scss is just the base of the final css used, it has to be compiled to take effect (never used last ionic so i cannot help further)

Comment: yes i'm use last version of ionic, i remove it already that css from my splash page but still the same.